# copy file to remote file share location using windows command prompt in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to copy a file from my source location to fileshare location.

```
source_path = "c:\\sourcepath\\filename.txt"
target_path = "\\\company.com\targetpath"
```

I tried the below command. It works.

```
os.system("cmd /k copy c:\\sourcepath\\filename.txt  \\\company.com\\targetpath")
```

But I want to pass the source & target path using variables. I tried the below command. its not working because the command is in quotes.

```
os.system("cmd /k copy source_path  target_path")
```

Please, help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first thing you tried works, it looks like you need to learn about Python's [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (link is to the official documentation).

Any of these should work for you:

```
os.system(f"cmd /k copy {source_path} {target_path}")
```

OR

```
os.system("cmd /k copy {source} {target}".format(source=source_path, target=target_path))
```

OR

```
os.system("cmd /k copy {} {}".format(source_path, target_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically construct the string using string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

In your case, you would can do the following

```
source_path = "c:\sourcepath\filename.txt"
target_path = "\\company.com\targetpath"

command_string = "cmd /k copy {} {}".format(source_path, target_path)

os.system(command_string)
```

Also, if you are on python3.6+ you can use f-strings. In that case you could replace the `command_string=...` line with

```
command_string = f"cmd /k copy {source_path} {target_path}"
```

Note the `f` at the beginning of the string. That makes it so that the things inside the braces are interpreted as variables.